# Specific Number format Python to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using a custom function and I am trying to apply a specific formatting to the output file that is sent to Excel.  I want positive/negative integers = 1234.34 to look like 1,234/(1,234).  The function I have works, but the output is a string and i would like it to show up as an integer/float/number in excel:

```
def formatter(x):
    if x > 0:
        return '{0:,.0f}'.format(x)
    else:
        return '({0:,.0f})'.format(abs(x))

for col in DFstats2.columns[1:]:
    DFstats2[col] = DFstats2[col].apply(formatter)
```

Currently for Excel to treat these as numbers, I have to right select 'convert to number' in order to do any kind of operations on them.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into `xlsxwriter`? You could just save the `DataFrame` to excel as it is and work on the format after that.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I have seen xlsxwriter- i was hoping to have a finished product based on formatting i am doing in the file without having to actually touch the output(excel file)

Answer (score 3):

If you want Excel to recognize your strings as formatted numbers, you will have to use `pd.ExcelWriter` formatting methods. Python string formatting can only produce, well, strings. Here's a trivial example:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_uppercase

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Positive': [1024.34, 2024.34, 3024.34, 4024.34],
                   'Negative': [-1024.34, -2024.34, -3024.34, -4024.34],
                   'Mixed': [1024.34, -2024.34, 3024.34, -4024.34]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Connect dataframe to Excel worksheet
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Formatted')

# Make handles for workbook/sheet
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Formatted']

# Create positive/negative cell format
pos_neg_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0;(#,##0)'})

# Define the worksheet range to apply number format
cols = dict(zip(range(26), ascii_uppercase))
row = len(df)
format_range = '{}{}:{}{}'.format(cols[0], row, cols[len(df.columns)-1], row)

# Apply number formats to specified range
worksheet.set_column(format_range, None, pos_neg_fmt)

writer.save()
```

The ExcelWriter methods give you tremendous flexibility to format your data in an Excel-specific way. You can even add conditional formatting, if you like. And you never have to touch the workbook, per your requirements.

Comment: T.Ray- thank you for your response- follow up question - what is the significance of '26' in range()  for the dict(zip(range() statement?  and what is the significance of 'ascii_uppercase'?  also, ascii_uppercase is not supported in my instance of python and unfortunately due to work constraints i am unable to import/install new modules- is there a workaround?  and lastly, what exactly does dict(zip(range(x), 'ascii_uppercase')) do?  thanks again for your help, but i am new to zip and the documentation is not clear to me.

Comment: `ascii_uppercase` is the uppercase English alphabet as a string, i.e. 'ABC...XYZ'. And `range(26)` is the number of letters. The idea, which may not be useful in your case, is to make (zip) a lookup table, i.e. dict, `{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C',..., 25: 'Z'}` that allows you to refer Excel columns by number.  You don't need to use this approach. You can just hard code the range e.g., 'A:A' or 'A:C' or 'A1:C4', etc.  The bottom line is that you need to specify a range in the Excel worksheet where you want to apply the number format.